# which thing is considered as LSB in PDF document?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, itext, document, pdfbox

In images, the LSB is the last bit of each pixel.

In PDF documents, what is the LSB?

I know that this question is difficult, because i thing that is related to the proposed method of concealment technique, but i would like to get your opinions.

So what is the thing in PDF that can be substituted by the bit of the message without modifying the document?

Best Regards,

Liszt

Comment: Do you actually search last significant bits of color information or just parts of values the change of which hardly changes the assistance at all?

Comment: Each character has color information ? so can we consider that LSB is the last significant bit of color information ? I don't know, just i ask this question because my supervisor has asked me this question and i have the curiosity to get the proper answer :) what is your opinion Dear micheal? :) and thanks in advance :)

Comment: and what is the other parts of values the change of which hardly changes the assistance at all ?

Comment: In PDFs you often have merely one color setting operation for all the content of one page (e.g. For a black on white page). That does not offer many bits for hidden messages. You can of course add many more such operations but it really would be quite suspicious to have many color selection operators differing only  insignificantly.

Comment: ah so in this case we can add different color for the text (so each character can take different color from the other), in this case we increase the number of embedded bits ?

Comment: *other parts of values the change of which hardly changes the assistance at all* - Oh,  i meant appearance, not assistance.  I had coordinates of vectors graphics on my mind, e.g. lines.  If coordinates are given as floats with many decimal places, the trailing digits may be manipulated without changing the visual appearance of the page in a recognizable manner.

Comment: For very colorful pages there likely are many color operations and, therefore, many less significant bits to play with without raising suspicion. For visually black and white pages, though, many color operations are suspicious.

Comment: sorry but about the second case "coordinates of vectors graphics", i don't understand this idea. Do you mean the coordinates of each line of the text? convert the decimal number of the coordinate of each line into binary and then change the LSB ? does that what do you mean?

Comment: Maybe you should explain *concealment technique* in Detail. Who shall a secret message be concealed from? A person only viewing the pdf in a PDF viewer? Or a person digging into the pdf internals?

Comment: for me,and in my method of concealment, a person only viewing the pdf in a PDF viewer.

Comment: There are many pages of PDFs with added vector graphics. E.g. text underlines are vector graphics. Table cell borders are vector graphics. Fancy company logos (at least those of good quality) are vector graphics. And whether the line goes from 46.0123, 87.6543 to 46.0123, 187.6543 or from 46.0124, 87.6542 to 46.0124, 187.6542 hardly makes a difference.

Comment: *a person only viewing the pdf in a PDF viewer* - for that use case trying to use less significant bits is kind of an overkill. Your use case can easily be covered using techniques like private streams, PDF Syntax comments, etc.

Comment: 46.0123, 87.6543 to 46.0123, 187.6543 ? how can you make that? why 187.6543 ?

Comment: The numbers were just examples for coordinates of the start and end of a line, and the other set of numbers were an example of a line with slightly different coordinates but visually virtually identical appearance.